# Add text to PrintDate Object

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

How to add text on the PrintDate Object instead of adding new textobject on the reports? the printdate only display 8/21/2013. How to have this `As of Printdate[8/21/2013] this are the list of employee`. What I mean of PrintDate Object is the default Field Object added when you create a report.

Answer (score 1):

"As of " & ToText(CurrentDate, "MMMM dd, yy") & " this are the list of employee:"